# Does Python have logical inversion mark like exclamation mark in Java?

Tags: python

Do Python have logical inversion mark like exclamation mark in Java?

In Java,

`bool myBool = true; 
 System.out.println(!myBool);` should give us the output "false".

But what about Python? In Python, is there any mark?

edit: I know the keyword "not". I am asking for a mark.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you are looking for. But __neg__ is with default dunder marks and can be used as : bool.__neg__(myBool), if it helps in anyway

Comment: @NafeezQuraishi that's negative, as in unary `-` (minus sign), not negate as in `not`.

Answer (score 9):

There is no `!`-like prefix operator for booleans in Python, for this we use `not`.

```py
>>> not True
False
>>> not False
True
>>> not 1
False
>>> not 0
True
```

There is a prefix (unary) bitwise not, `~`, but since Python's integers are signed integers that grow in size instead of rolling over, it's harder to demonstrate it.

```py
>>> ~0b00000001
-2
```

But you can see it if you use a mask of all ones (for the number of bits in your integer) and format it correctly:

```py
>>> f'{~(-2) & 0b11111111:08b}'
'00000001'
>>> f'{~(~(-2)) & 0b11111111:08b}'
'11111110'
```

This is generally only useful for bitwise operations, though.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have any such mark. As you seem to already know, the `not` keyword is what is used in Python. You can use `!=` to mean "not equal to" but that's it.